# Combine MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way I can combine these two MySQL queries? It's currently making sorting and pagination etc really difficult.

```
SELECT *
FROM (`lb_sales`)
WHERE `recurring` =  '0'
AND `created` >= '2012-10-01 00:00:00'
AND `created` <= '2012-10-30 23:59:59'
AND `status` =  'pending'
AND `type` =  'sale'
AND `account_id` =  '2'
ORDER BY `id` ASC
LIMIT 5;

SELECT *
FROM (`lb_sales`)
WHERE `recurring` =  '1'
AND `created` <= '2012-10-30 23:59:59'
AND `status` =  'pending'
AND `type` =  'sale'
AND `account_id` =  '2'
ORDER BY `id` ASC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: As can be seen by a lot of the comments down below, your limit could be a problem. Is it important to have 5 of both types of records or would 5 total work, or would 10 total work? Also what setup are you using for pagination and sorting? Is it server-side or client-side? Is it a framework or something you wrote yourself? With these being such small returns, it may pay off more to look at your pagination setup then to focus on combining these two records.

Comment: @FrankB: The `UNION` [proposed by @njk](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13686163) overcomes the `LIMIT` issues.

Comment: Thanks for the great response. I'm using CodeIgniter for Pagination and Sorting. It should return up to 10 results.

Comment: FrankMartin So if I understand correctly just setting the limit to 10 will on most of the answer below will suffice for your needs? @eggyal You are absolutely correct, hence it getting my upvote. But if he just wants the top 10 of a recordset that meets either criteria then the UNION is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM (`lb_sales`)
WHERE ((`recurring` =  '0'
AND `created` >= '2012-10-01 00:00:00'
AND `created` <= '2012-10-30 23:59:59')
OR (`recurring` =  '1'
AND `created` <= '2012-10-30 23:59:59'))
AND `status` =  'pending'
AND `type` =  'sale'
AND `account_id` =  '2'
ORDER BY `id` ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: The original queries returned up to 5 records each (i.e. up to 10 in total), whereas this query returns at most 5 of those 10.

Comment: Good point... I've set the limit to 10 but obviously there's no guarantee that the result set will yield 5 rows from recurring=0 set and 5 rows from recurring=1 set.

Answer (score 1):

Try `UNION ALL`, just make sure that the columns align. Also, don't use `SELECT *`. Always specify a column list.

```
SELECT col1, col2, ...
FROM (`lb_sales`)
WHERE `recurring` =  '0'
AND `created` >= '2012-10-01 00:00:00'
AND `created` <= '2012-10-30 23:59:59'
AND `status` =  'pending'
AND `type` =  'sale'
AND `account_id` =  '2'
ORDER BY `id` ASC
LIMIT 5
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, ...
FROM (`lb_sales`)
WHERE `recurring` =  '1'
AND `created` <= '2012-10-30 23:59:59'
AND `status` =  'pending'
AND `type` =  'sale'
AND `account_id` =  '2'
ORDER BY `id` ASC
LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM (`lb_sales`)
WHERE
(
`recurring` =  '0'
AND `created` >= '2012-10-01 00:00:00'
AND `created` <= '2012-10-30 23:59:59'
)
OR
( 
`recurring` =  '1'
AND `created` <= '2012-10-30 23:59:59'
)
AND `status` =  'pending'
AND `type` =  'sale'
AND `account_id` =  '2'
ORDER BY `id` ASC
LIMIT 5;
```

Parentheses are your friend young padwan. Of course I'm assuming you want records that meet either criteria.

Comment: Not the same, your query can return 5 rows, his original query could return 10 rows.

Comment: You're right, but as you can tell it's something we all didn't address. I've asked a question to the original question to see if we can get more info about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT *  FROM (`lb_sales`)
WHERE (`recurring` =  '0' AND `created` >= '2012-10-01 00:00:00'
 AND `created` <= '2012-10-30 23:59:59' ) 
OR (`recurring` =  '1' AND `created` <= '2012-10-30 23:59:59')    
AND `status` =  'pending'
AND `type` =  'sale'
AND `account_id` =  '2'
ORDER BY `id` ASC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: The original queries returned up to 5 records each (i.e. up to 10 in total), whereas this query returns at most 5 of those 10.

Comment: The OP can change the `limit` as per his need.

Comment: But if he wants to return the same records as in his original queries, merely adjusting this `LIMIT` clause won't achieve that.  Suppose that one sets `LIMIT 10` but there are 5 more records from `recurring = 1` that are ordered before any of those from `recurring = 0`.

Comment: correct, so he needs to figure out how/what how many rows he wants to get, in the combined query.

Comment: But my point is that it's quite likely no value for `LIMIT` will return the same results as those in the original two queries.

Comment: He can also use the `UNION` as njk suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (`lb_sales`)
WHERE ( `recurring` =  '0' 
AND `created` >= '2012-10-01 00:00:00'
AND `created` <= '2012-10-30 23:59:59'
AND `status` =  'pending'
AND `type` =  'sale'
AND `account_id` =  '2' ) 
OR  (`recurring` =  '1'
AND `created` <= '2012-10-30 23:59:59'
AND `status` =  'pending'
AND `type` =  'sale'
AND `account_id` =  '2' )
ORDER BY `id` ASC
LIMIT 5;
```

maybe something like this but not shure if the syntax is correct

Comment: The original queries returned up to 5 records each (i.e. up to 10 in total), whereas this query returns at most 5 of those 10.

Comment: thats becouse u have to change the limit at the end

Comment: But if he wants to return the same records as in his original queries, merely adjusting this `LIMIT` clause won't achieve that.  Suppose that one sets `LIMIT 10` but there are 5 more records from `recurring = 1` that are ordered before any of those from `recurring = 0`.

Comment: Then there is no chance that he can achieve this whit one query, maybe an sql script with cursors could help

Comment: A single `UNION` query would do the trick, [as proposed by @njk](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13686163).